# Distinct most recent data from database Grouped by Column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am storing data in my database. The data being stored looks like this

```
   vin                    date_traitement
    VF15R060H54847102   2018-04-05 00:00:00
    UU1HSDC9553072004   2017-08-07 15:01:00
    UU1HSDC9553072004   2017-08-07 14:51:00
    VF15R060H54847102   2017-08-07 14:57:00
```

Within my Controller I am trying to retrieve the distinct vin, but get the latest inserted version for each to get extracted to excel. At the moment I am trying

```
 return Bddrenault::groupBy('vin')->orderBy('date_traitement', 'desc')
             ->get()
             ->map(function ($item, $key) {
             return (array) $item;
             })
             ->all();
```

The problem is that this is returning the excel file empty and im trying to get this

```
  vin                    date_traitement
    VF15R060H54847102   2018-04-05 00:00:00
    UU1HSDC9553072004   2017-08-07 15:01:00
```

How am I able to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Please share your try and specify where you got stuck ?

Comment: [Stack Overflow isn't a code translation service](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265834/354577).

Comment: I didn't ask for code translation im stuck cuz i am  getting no data in my excel file, can you show me where im wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
$join = Bddrenault::select('vin')
    ->selectRaw('MAX(`date_traitement`) `date_traitement`')
    ->groupBy('vin');
$sql = '(' . $join->toSql() . ') as `voiture`';
Bddrenault::select('id', 'bd.vin', 'bd.date_traitement')
    ->from('bddrenaults as bd')
    ->join(DB::raw($sql), function($join) {
        $join->on('bd.vin', 'voiture.vin')
            ->on('bd.date_traitement', 'voiture.date_traitement');
    })->get();
```